# How to get an output out of arrays without using pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, null

Firstly i am new to this site and i wanted your help to solve this small problem as i am a beginner in C programming.

Here's my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
main()
{
 char user[10],temp[10];
 int t;
 printf("Welcome to the game of guessing\nThere are 2 choices namely a,and b\n");
 getch();
 printf("You just have to guess and see if u are lucky\n");
 getch();
 printf("Type a letter from a and b choices\n");
 scanf("%s",&user[0]);
 srand(time(NULL));
 t=rand();
 if(t%2==0)
 {
      char temp[0]="a";
 }else
 {
      char temp[0]="b";
 }
 if(strncmp(temp,user,1)==0)
 {
      printf("You have guessed right. The answer is %s",user[0]);
 }else
 {
      printf("You have guessed wrong. The answer is %s, try again",temp[0]);
 }
 getch();

}
```

Well this code creates a simple guessing game kinda thing where you have to enter an input and if the your input tallys with that of computer's then you will win or else you will lose.

The problem that i am having is in those last printf statements. Look at the last printf

printf("You have guessed wrong. The answer is %s, try again",temp[0]);

Here the output is kinda like this.

You have guessed wrong. The answer is **null**, try again

So whats this **null** and how do i make it get what temp holds.

Also i am always getting the output as wrong. is there a way i can fix this? since this is based on equal probability, i think i should be able to get equal choices between a and b.

Thanks.

Comment: You're defining a local zero length array named `temp` here - `char temp[0]="a";`. Get rid of `char` and use `strcpy` or `strncpy` to copy `"a"` into `temp`

Comment: Maybe using character literals rather than strings in your assignments and terminating your string properly would help. A review of what [**`printf`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format specifiers expect would be advisable as well. Unrelated: include the proper headers (you're missing at least two), and properly declare `int main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete "char" in first if and else and change "a" to 'a' and "b" to 'b'.

And in printf should be

```
printf("You have guessed right. The answer is %c",user[0]);
```

instead of

```
printf("You have guessed right. The answer is %s",user[0]);
```

The same in second printf